# jQuery - Disable list of links and move active link down the list in sequence

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, navigation

I'm trying to test the effectiveness of a navigational function in my prototype. On the left side of the page, I have an unordered list with 30 list items that flows off of the page. On the right side of the page is a prompt that is asking users to click through the navigational items in a randomized sequence.

The right and left side are displayed inside of iFrames, with the clicks on the left navigation updating the content on the right and in turn prompting users to click on the next item in the sequence. I'd like to avoid having all 30 list items live at once, to avoid test users erroneously clicking any item other than the next item in the sequence. Is it possible, using jQuery (or anything else, for that matter), to have the HREF in the navigation track the order of my sequence and link each item when it appears in the sequence and be *unlinked* when it does not appear next in the sequence?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I've made a bit of headway here. My javascript is still not producing the desired result (*disable all links except for the current link in the sequence, and once click, disable the link and activate the next one in the sequence*). I've simplified the scope of the list to make the problem easier to handle for now.

```
var linkInterceptor = function(event) {
    if($(event.target).hasClass("active")) {
        $('a').removeClass("active");

// assume links have class="nextlink_##"
var nextTarget = $(event.target).getAttr('class');
var nextId = nextTarget.substr(9);
$('#' + nextId).addClass("active");

return true;
} else {
event.preventDefault();
}
};

$('a').on('click', linkInterceptor);
```

And here is the HTML

```
<div style="width:1024px; height:768px;">
    <div style="width:298px; height:708px; overflow:scroll; float:left;">
            <a class="nextlink_2" id="1" target="frame2" href="instruction_2.html">img</a>
            <a class="nextlink_3" id="2" target="frame2" href="instruction_3.html">img</a>
            <a class="nextlink_4" id="3" target="frame2" href="instruction_4.html">img</a>
            <a class="nextlink_5" id="4" target="frame2" href="instruction_5.html">img</a>
            <a id="5" target="frame2" href="instruction_6.html">img</a>
    </div>
    <div style="width:726px; float:left;">
        <iframe src="instruction_1.html" width="726" height="100%" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" id="frame2"></iframe>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Any idea where I'm going astray?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Why do they need navigation at all if they have to go through in a sequence anyway? Can't you just give them a "next" button or something?

Comment: A "next" button won't work because were timing the sequence and how long it takes them to click through the random sequence of 30 list items. They must click on the items in sequence. I've tried the solution I described above (nav. in iFrame 1 cycles through sequence prompts in iFrame 2). That's a problem because all links in iFrame 1 were active and I want one active at a time in the sequence. Right now, I have a version that uses a ton of static pages to get the prototype working, but iFrame one reloads each time and I'd like to prevent that in order to hold the position after clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Below is the code to deactivate the links in the list, step through a pre-determined, unordered sequence based on link ID and, on click, deactivate a link and activate the next in the sequence. The javascript:

```
<script>
    var linkInterceptor = function(event) {
    if($(event.target).hasClass("active")) {
    $('a').removeClass("active");

    // assume links have class="nextlink_##"
    var nextTarget = $(event.target).attr('class');
    var nextId = nextTarget.substr(9);
    $('#' + nextId).addClass("active");

    return true;
    } else {
    event.preventDefault();
    }
    };

    $('a').on('click', linkInterceptor);
</script>
```

And a sample of the final HTML:

```
    <div style="width:1024px; height:768px;">
    <div style="width:298px; height:708px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x:hidden; float:left; padding-bottom:-20px; margin-bottom:-20px;">
        <li><a class="nextlink_13" id="12" target="frame2" href="instruction_13.html">Name 1</a></li>
        <li><a class="nextlink_11" id="10" target="frame2" href="instruction_11.html">Name 2</a></li>
        <li><a class="nextlink_20" id="19" target="frame2" href="instruction_20.html">Name 3</a></li>
        <li><a class="nextlink_3" id="2" target="frame2" href="instruction_3.html">Name 4</a></li>
        <li><a class="nextlink_16" id="15" target="frame2" href="instruction_16.html">Name 5</a></li>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The list is 30 names long so I've truncated it above. To achieve the planned randomness, I just numbered the IDs based on the order we preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a small JSFiddle that works. http://jsfiddle.net/79ZFR/

Essentially I remove the current click handler and then add a click handler to the next number.

```
    function AddClick(number) {
        $("#" + number).click(function () {
            $("#" + number).off('click');
            AddClick(number+1);
        });
    }​
```

Then all you need to do is to initialize it on load.

```
    $(function () {
        AddClick(1);
    });
```

My HTML is:

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="1" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a id="2" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a id="3" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a id="4" href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a id="5" href="#">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

but if you want it randomized then you can easily do that in the back end.

I didn't use any iframes in this.

NOTE: For your final one you'll need to handle your stop timer event.

EDIT:

For a randomized list I would do it on the back end and generate my HTML like

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="5" href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a id="3" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a id="1" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a id="4" href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a id="2" href="#">2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. One more question: we're trying for an ordered random sequence, meaning a sequence like 3,9,22,4,16, etc. that we can specify. Is there a way to augment the function to specify the sequence instead of adding "1" or being truly random?

Comment: see update, I'm not sure what you're using on the backend so I can't help you with that at the moment.

Comment: Just a follow up: I've been playing around with this a bit. I have my list and have numbered the ids so that they follow the "random" sequence that we want the prototype to follow. A couple of behaviors that I still can't get to work are all of the links being deactivated EXCEPT for the next link in the sequence and that once the user clicks on that link, it is deactivated and the next one in the sequence is activated, and so on.

Comment: Weird, are you using the script that is in the JS Fiddle? That one allows you to click on the anchor tag, but nothing happens if you don't click on the correct one. What happens when you click on the incorrect link?

Comment: Sorry, I must have botched something in the implementation. Here is what I'm working with [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nerdelite/SzStS/). I've stripped out the URLs in the links, but essentially I have one div with a list of names, a second div with an iFrame calling in the next name in the order. The names are lifted alphabetically but their IDs are jumbled to provide for a bit of a search from the user testing the prototype. Has the structure of my page or the numbering of the links messed up the interaction with the javascript?